# Broccoli Plugin permission error, nodejs

Tags: ember.js, ubuntu-14.04, virtualbox, ember-cli

I am getting a build error when trying to run a node.js app on Ubuntu (run as Guest OS on Windows 10). How do I solve the permission error below?

```
Build error

The Broccoli Plugin: [BroccoliMergeTrees] failed with:

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/<PROJECT_FOLDER>/tmp'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:842:18)
    at findBaseDir (/<PROJECT_FOLDER>/node_modules/quick-temp/index.js:62:8)
    at makeTmpDir (/<PROJECT_FOLDER>/node_modules/quick-temp/index.js:45:41)
    at Object.makeOrReuse (/<PROJECT_FOLDER>/node_modules/quick-temp/index.js:21:22)
    at new ReadCompat (/<PROJECT_FOLDER>/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/read_compat.js:17:13)
    at BroccoliMergeTrees.Plugin._initializeReadCompat (/<PROJECT_FOLDER>/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/index.js:130:22)
    at BroccoliMergeTrees.Plugin.read (/<PROJECT_FOLDER>/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/index.js:110:12)
    at /<PROJECT_FOLDER>/node_modules/ember-cli-broccoli/lib/builder.js:107:23
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/<PROJECT_FOLDER>/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1036:16)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at: 
    at BroccoliMergeTrees.Plugin (/<PROJECT_FOLDER>/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/index.js:7:31)
    at new BroccoliMergeTrees (/<PROJECT_FOLDER>/node_modules/broccoli-merge-trees/index.js:29:10)
    at BroccoliMergeTrees (/<PROJECT_FOLDER>/node_modules/broccoli-merge-trees/index.js:23:53)
    at Class.module.exports.postprocessTree (/<PROJECT_FOLDER>/node_modules/broccoli-serviceworker/lib/ember-addon.js:62:14)
    at /<PROJECT_FOLDER>/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:506:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at EmberApp.addonPostprocessTree (/<PROJECT_FOLDER>/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:504:23)
    at EmberApp.toTree (/<PROJECT_FOLDER>/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1591:15)
    at module.exports (/<PROJECT_FOLDER>/ember-cli-build.js:36:16)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.setupBroccoliBuilder (/<PROJECT_FOLDER>/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/builder.js:55:19)
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the owner `sudo chown <yourusername>:admin <path to your project>`?

Comment: I have just tried that but it throws an error: `chown: invalid group: ‘username:admin’`

Comment: Try it without the group then. [Here's a few good suggestions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership)

Comment: no luck, still getting the same error in browser after that permission change attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you installed node.js/npm with the wrong permissions. You should check the [Fixing npm permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) official guide for guidance.